# Bug with NAudio, play mp3 in MemoryStream, VB

Tags: vb.net, naudio

I have a function to read my mp3 from my Resources that work very well.

Unfortunately, if I pass my mouse 30, 40 or 50 times on my button it ends up by a crash on the `waveOut.init`: `( {" AlreadyAllocated calling waveOutOpen "} )`

```
Public waveOut As WaveOut = New WaveOut

Private Sub Panel_Bouton_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel_Bouton.MouseEnter
    Play_Sound()
End Sub

Public Sub Play_Sound()
    Dim mp3file As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(My.Resources.Clic)
    'Clic.mp3 is in my Resources
    Dim mp3Reader As Mp3FileReader = New Mp3FileReader(mp3file)

    If waveOut.PlaybackState = PlaybackState.Playing Then
        waveOut.Stop()
        ' I tried this but no effect...
    End If

    waveOut.Init(mp3Reader)
    waveOut.Play()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against constantly calling Init on `WaveOut`. Instead, just have one (and it looks like you can have just one `Mp3FileReader` as well), and then in the `Play_Sound` function, set `mp3Reader.Position = 0` and restart your `WaveOut` instance if it's stopped. (I'm assuming from your code snippet that you never want to be playing more than one instance of the sound at once).